# Actions are not triggering when alerts are triggered

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

Using Terraform I have created Alert, Action group and Logicapp. (Code-1 show below)

Action to trigger when an alert is triggered, where one of Action type is Logic app, which was as expected. Alert got triggered when condition is true further it trigger Logic app action.

Later, I got requirement to adjust alert’s threshold and frequency and made changes to Terraform code, while doing plan/apply noticed only changes in Alert Frequency and threshold value and these are expected. (Code-2 show below)

After this change(update) of Alert properties action as stopped functioning. when alert is triggered, Action is not triggered.

**Test 1: Checking weather alert itself truly triggering**

•   Just to test the functionality of alert whether itself getting triggered, I subscribed Notification type to send mail to my Inbox. Which worked and I got mail regarding the alert but the alert unable to trigger action.

**Test 1.2: Changes from Portal**

•   I removed testing-logicapp (Logic app action) under Action type from Azure Portal.

•   And Added testing-logicapp (Logic app action) under Action type from Azure Portal. (As show in below JPG-3)

•   This resulted Action to trigger when an alert is triggered.

So, my doubt is, how should I handle this scenario in terraform way.

**Code-1** :

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "myvm_task_alert_v2" {
  name                = "myvm-auto-deletion-alert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myvm_task_resource_group.name
  evaluation_frequency = "PT1H"
  window_duration      = "PT1H"
  scopes               = [data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.id]

  severity             = 4
  criteria {
    query                   = <<-QUERY
        Perf
        | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
        | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total" 
        | project TimeGenerated, Computer, CounterValue, _ResourceId
        | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue)  by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer, _ResourceId   
      QUERY
    time_aggregation_method = "Maximum"
    threshold               = 30.0
    operator                = "LessThan"
    metric_measure_column = "AggregatedValue"

  }

  display_name                     = "myvm-auto-deletion-alert"
  enabled                          = true
  action {
    action_groups = [azurerm_monitor_action_group.delete_myvm_action_group.id]
  }
}



resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "delete_myvm_action_group" {
  name                = "myvm-auto-deletion-action-group"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myvm_task_resource_group.name
  short_name          = "myvm-autodel"
  tags                = module.metadata.tags

  logic_app_receiver {
    name                    = "myvm-auto-deletion-logicapp"
    resource_id             = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.myvm_task_logicapp.id
    callback_url            = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.myvm_task_logicapp.access_endpoint
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "sendtoPraveen"
    email_address           = "praveen@goog.gov.net"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

}


resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "myvm_task_logicapp" {
  name                = "myvm-auto-deletion-logicapp"
  location            = "us east"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myvm_task_resource_group.name
}
```

**Code-2** :

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "myvm_task_alert_v2" {
  name                = "myvm-auto-deletion-alert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myvm_task_resource_group.name
  evaluation_frequency = "PT1H"
  window_duration      = "PT10H" ####################-------------------->change1
  scopes               = [data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.id]

  severity             = 4
  criteria {
    query                   = <<-QUERY
        Perf
        | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
        | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total" 
        | project TimeGenerated, Computer, CounterValue, _ResourceId
        | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue)  by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer, _ResourceId   
      QUERY
    time_aggregation_method = "Maximum"
    threshold               = 50.0 ####################-------------------->change2
    operator                = "LessThan"
    metric_measure_column = "AggregatedValue"

  }

  display_name                     = "myvm-auto-deletion-alert"
  enabled                          = true
  action {
    action_groups = [azurerm_monitor_action_group.delete_myvm_action_group.id]
  }
}
```

**JPG-1**
[image: Changes from Portal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue with the help of MIcrosoft support team.
Created new azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request flow.

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request" "logic_app_httptrigger_code" {
  name         = "alertv2httPayload"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.myvm_task_logicapp.id

  schema = data.local_file.httptrigger_code.content
}
```

You'll need to use callbackurl of azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request in Logic_app_receiver under actiongroup  :

```
azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request.logic_app_httptrigger_code.callback_url
```

instead of

```
azurerm_logic_app_workflow.myvm_task_logicapp.access_endpoint
```

Ref : [Action groups not triggering Logic Apps #6056](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6056#issuecomment-1284598127)

Answer (score -1):

> Actions are not triggering when alerts are triggered:

I tried it in my environment by using this  [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2#arguments-reference)  template for scheduled alerts and making a few modifications as required. It was successfully deployed, and an action was triggered with appropriate information to the specified user's email address.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.37.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxxexample-resources"
  location = "xxxxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "xxxxexample-ai"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
  name                = "xxxxdeletion-logicapp"
  location            = "eastUS"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  name                = "xxxxx-mag"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "xxxxxtest"
  logic_app_receiver {
    name                    = "xxxxxdeletion-logicapp"
    resource_id             = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.example.id
    callback_url            = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.example.access_endpoint
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "sendtouser"
    email_address           = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "example" {
  name                = "xxxx-msqrv2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  evaluation_frequency = "PT10M"
  window_duration      = "PT10M"
  scopes               = [azurerm_application_insights.example.id]
  severity             = 4
  criteria {
        query                   = <<-QUERY
      requests
        | summarize CountByCountry=count() by client_CountryOrRegion #Give query condition as per your requirements
      QUERY   
    time_aggregation_method = "Maximum"
    threshold               = 30.0
    operator                = "LessThan"
    metric_measure_column = "CountByCountry"
    resource_id_column    = "client_CountryOrRegion"
    
    dimension {
      name     = "client_CountryOrRegion"
      operator = "Exclude"
      values   = ["123"]
    }
    failing_periods {
      minimum_failing_periods_to_trigger_alert = 1
      number_of_evaluation_periods             = 1
    }
  }
  auto_mitigation_enabled          = true
  workspace_alerts_storage_enabled = false
  description                      = "example sqr"
  display_name                     = "example-sqr"
  enabled                          = true
  query_time_range_override        = "PT1H"
  skip_query_validation            = true
  action {
    action_groups = [azurerm_monitor_action_group.example.id]
    custom_properties = {
      key1  = "xxx"
      key2 = "xxx"
    }
  }
  tags = {
    key1  = "xxxx"
  }
}
```

***terraform init:***

[image]

***terraform plan:***

[image]

***terraform apply:***

[image]

***Deployed in Portal & added an action group:***

[image]

***Triggered alert mail successfully:***

[image]

Comment: Ok , Now try to change some properties(threshold or frequency) in Alert via terraform and check whether all the configured actions are able to trigger.

Comment: My case i tried to change Frequency and threshold of the alert from Terraform , which made action(logic app) stopped working , but mail notification working as expected.

Comment: @praveen I changed the threshold to [17.0](https://i.imgur.com/7ZR4OOu.png) and executed [terraform apply](https://i.imgur.com/kKOHEwQ.png). It is working as expected. [Logic app](https://i.imgur.com/6D1OW0Z.png) is also working fine.

Comment: I tried to replicate the same with different subscription , but still facing same issue.

Comment: Declare the new subscription Id as an env variable in terraform and try again. @praveen

Comment: FYI,  I replicated multiple time in different existing subscription and new subscription but still same issue

Comment: Can you delete the action group and create once again using terraform!

Comment: Deleted action group and recreated it ,now alerts are triggering actions. Now i made changes to alert (increases threshold to 50.0) and again actions stopped triggering. @Jahnavi